# D3 transition leaves trails while moving a foreignObject Element

Tags: html, reactjs, d3.js

I am using D3 js to append an HTML block to an SVG using foreignObject.
Once appended I am selecting the element by id and changing the x,y attribute to move

`d3.select("#" + id) .transition() .ease(d3.easeLinear) .duration(1000) .attr("x", "100") .attr("y", "220")`

The transtion happens as expected but it leaves a trail of lines some times, Issue couldnt be reproduced consistantly

[image]

foreignObject is the only way to group HTML elements and append it to an SVG.
Tried to change the duration, transition time, CPU throttling, adding the block in  window.requestAnimationFrame -It is not helping